# OpenLayers map refresh

Tags: openlayers

I'm trying to reinitialize my map upon modal open. But it seems that after the modal open all I can see is the map controls but the other layers is not visible. Below is my code

```
<div id="map_container" class="col-md-12 row wrapper" style="position: fixed;width: inherit;overflow: hidden;padding-left: 0;top:50px;z-index:3;">
        <div id="map" class="map"></div>
        <div class="loader_container row">
            <img src="images/Icons/loading.gif" />
            Loading please wait
        </div>
        <div id="progress"></div>
</div>
```

Modal markup

```
<div class="modal fade" id="map-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mapModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-container map-modal wrapper">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([
        new ol.control.FullScreen()
    ]),
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: this.source
        }),

        new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: this.marker_layer
            // opacity: 0.7
        })
    ],
    loadTilesWhileAnimating: true,
    view: new ol.View(this.view)
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.modal-container.map-modal').html($('#map_container').html());
    openModal();
});

function openModal()
{
  $("#map-modal").modal('show');
}

$('#map-modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
     map.updateSize();
});
```

Everything is working fine if I'm viewing the map on first load and not on the modal. But if I try to implement and add the map content in a modal and try to view it by trigger the modal show it's not displaying any information on the map except the controls

Comment: what about to use `setSize` as modal size. if map size is [0, 0] then it's no changes from `updateSize`

Comment: @ChaseChoi this didn't work either

Comment: did you try `setSize` with `updateSize`?

Comment: Yup tried both of them. I just did a workaround and reinitialize the map